# 3rd character of the string is not reversing the code given below

Tags: c, for-loop, reverse, c-strings

How can I assign third character to fourth character?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {

    char a[50];
    int i,l,temp;

    setbuf(stdout,NULL);
    printf("enter a string");

    scanf("%s",a);
    l=strlen(a);

    for(i=0;i<=l/2;i++){
        temp=a[i];
        a[i]=a[l-i-1];
        a[l-i-1]=temp;
    }

    printf("%s",a);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

output:

enter a stringamalks

skalma

Comment: Unrelated: `scanf("%s",...)` does not read spaces. Use `fgets()` for user input. Also `scanf()` is notoriously difficult to use correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your immediate problem is that your loop is execuing one more time than you expect.

Assuming input is `"amalks"` .. and therefore `l` is `6`

```
for(i=0;i<=l/2;i++)
```

goes

```
i = 0;                     // swap a and s
i = 1;                     // swap m and k
i = 2;                     // swap a and l
i = 3; // 3 <= 6/2         // swap l and a
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason of the problem is the incorrect condition in the for loop:

```
for(i=0;i<=l/2;i++){
        ^^^^^^
```

When `l` is an even number then you have that `i` will be equal to `l / 2` and the expression `a[l-i-1]` will be equivalent to `a[l-l / 2-1]` that is the same as `a[l /2 - 1]`.

Change the condition of the loop the following way:

```
for(i=0;i < l/2;i++){
        ^^^^^^
```

Pay attention to that as the function `strlen` has the return `size_t` then the variables `l` and `i` also should have the type `size_t`.

And the call of `scanf` should look either like:

```
scanf("%49s",a);
```

or like

```
scanf("%49[^\n]",a);
```

to avoid the array memory overflow.